# static pre-calculation optimization in clang

Tags: c, optimization, clang

I have

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fib(int n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

double clock_now()
{
    struct timeval now;

    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    return (double)now.tv_sec + (double)now.tv_usec/1.0e6;
}

#define NITER 5
```

and in my `main()`, I'm doing a simple benchmark like this:

```
printf("hi\n");
double t = clock_now();
int f = 0;
double tmin = INFINITY;
for (int i=0; i<NITER; ++i) {
    printf("run %i, %f\n", i, clock_now()-t);
    t = clock_now();
    f += fib(40);
    t = clock_now()-t;
    printf("%i %f\n", f, t);
    if (t < tmin) tmin = t;
    t = clock_now();
}
printf("fib,%.6f\n", tmin*1000);
```

When I compile with `clang -O3` (LLVM 5.0 from Xcode 5.0.1), it always prints out zero time, except at the init of the `for`-loop, i.e. this:

```
hi
run 0, 0.866536
102334155 0.000000
run 1, 0.000001
204668310 0.000000
run 2, 0.000000
307002465 0.000000
run 3, 0.000000
409336620 0.000000
run 4, 0.000001
511670775 0.000000
fib,0.000000
```

It seems that it statically precalculates the `fib(40)` and stores it somewhere. Right? The strange lag at the beginning (0.8 secs) is probably because it loads that cache?

I'm doing this for benchmarking. The C compiler should optimize `fib()` itself as much as it can. However, I don't want it to precalculate it already at compile time. So basically I want all code optimized as heavily as possible, but not `main()` (or at least not this specific optimization). Can I do that somehow?

What optimization is it anyway in this specific case? It's somehow strange and quite nice.

Comment: Side note: `gettimeofday` is obsolete and `clock_gettime` is preferred now.

Comment: You could try to put the code inside the loop in a function, which is passed the value to call `fib` with as an argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Well, even if that works now, maybe a future version will be even more clever and also optimize that away, so that doesn't seem like a reliable solution.

Comment: Side note to @Shahbaz: Mac OS X does not have `clock_gettime()` so the code is correct to use `gettimeofday()` as a decent alternative.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembler that is generated to see if that explains anything?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, right. That function has been marked as obsolete in POSIX2008. Seems like Apple is almost as ignorant w.r.t. POSIX as Microsoft is.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by marking certain data `volatile`. Esp, what I did was:

```
volatile int f = 0;
//...
    volatile int FibArg = 40;
    f += fib(FibArg);
```

That way, it forces the compiler to read `FibArg` when calling the function and it forces it to not assume that it is constant. Thus it must call the function to calculate it.

The `volatile int f` was not necessary for my compiler at the moment but it might be in the future when the compiler figures out that `fib` has no side effects and its result nor `f` is every used.

---

Note that this is still not the end. A future compiler could have advanced so far that it guesses that `40` is a likely argument for `fib`. Maybe it builds a database for likely values. And for the most likely values, it builds up a small cache. And when `fib` is called, it does a fast runtime-check whether it has that value cached. Of course, the runtime-check adds some overhead but maybe the compiler estimates that this overhead is minor for some particular code in relation to the speed gained by the cached.

I'm not sure if a compiler will ever do such optimization but it could. Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) goes already in that direction.